# How to create a stand alone .exe DotNetCore WebApi application in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to create a stand alone .exe DotNetCore 1.1 WebApi application in Visual Studio 2017, however I can't find any documentation.

The Microsoft documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/deploying/deploy-with-vs only covers a console application, and following the modifications to the .csproj doesn't change anything.

```
<RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
```

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Normally you run you ASP.NET Core (Web API included) application on a web server (IIS, Apache, Nginx etc), so its not really a standalone and won't be an EXE. Please clarify - what is the goal of the app, why do you need an EXE?

Comment: I want to deploy it as a Service Fabric guest executable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, after a bit of digging I've figured it out.

In the .csproj...

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
<RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
```

Then...

```
PM> dotnet restore
PM> dotnet publish -c release -r win10-x64
```

Check the `bin/Release/win10-x64` directory and your self contained app will be there. Bonza.

Answer (score 1):

A console application *is* a stand-alone application, i.e. one that doesn't require a web server like IIS or Kestrel to run. However it still needs the .net runtime to be present on all the machines you run the program on, so in that case its not stand alone. to fix this, just bundle the .net runtime with your console app.

Furthermore, if you create a console application you can then use external tools to register it as a Windows service if you wish.