# Dotnet publish looking for exe on resource group project

Tags: .net, azure, publish, azure-resource-group

I have a solution with a web API on it, as well as an Azure resource group project.
Everything was working fine until I added that resource group project, because when trying to use dotnet publish, it throws an error saying that it couldn't find the .exe file under the bin folder for that resource group project.
As far as I understand, it'll not find it, because that project doesn't produce a .exe. It only has JSON files and a powershell script and that's all.

If my assumption is correct. Is there any way to let dotnet publish know that it should not expect a .exe from that project, but still get the JSON and powershell files into the outputs, along with the binaries for the API?

Comment: Try cleaning the project and rebuilding it.

Comment: Doesn't work. Actually this started happening on a jenkins pipeline, then I tried to replicate it locally and same issue. For some reason, dotnet publish really wants a .exe to be produced by that Azure Resource Group project

Answer (score 0):

One of the workaround can resolve the above issue.

- To Create an .exe file we need to add the following in our `.csproj` file according to your version that you are using ,In my case i have  `.net6`

  ```
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
          <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
      </PropertyGroup
  ```

[image]

- Run `dotnet restore`  then try to run the `dotnet publish` cmd .

For more information please refer the below links:

- MS DOC: [How to create a publish profile in VS STUDIO.](https://jakeydocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/publishing/web-publishing-vs.html) & [`MS BUILD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish#msbuild)
- SO THREAD :  [create a stand alone .exe DotNetCore WebApi application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43662368/how-to-create-a-stand-alone-exe-dotnetcore-webapi-application-in-visual-studio)